# How to get A,B and C given XYZ?

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, polynomials

How do I get $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Given

$$X=\frac{a+\frac{1}2b}{a+b+c}$$

$$Y=\frac{b(\frac{\sqrt3}{2})}{a+b+c}$$

$$Z=\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

in other words How do i get $a$, $b$, and $c$ on the left side using these three formulas?

please help me find A= or B= or C= on the left.
For a total of 3 equations.

I need this formula to use in a robot. Color matching algorithm.

the answer should look like this.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the equations

$a = Z \left(3 X-\sqrt{3} Y\right)$

$b = 2 \sqrt{3} Y Z$

$c = Z \left(-\left(3 X+\sqrt{3}  Y-3\right)\right)$

Comment: Wow that was quick. This is right. Also, cool how you used the X, Y, and Z only once in each.

Answer (score 1):

From the last equation, we get $a+b++c=3Z$. Substituting in the first two equations, and simplifying a bit, we get
$$3XZ=a+\frac{1}{2}b,\tag{1}$$
and
$$3YZ=b\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.\tag{2}$$

The second equation gives $b=\frac{(2)(3YZ)}{\sqrt{3}}$, which simplifies to $b=(2YZ)\sqrt{3}$.

Now from the first equation we get $a=3XZ-YZ\sqrt{3}$.

Finally, since $a+b+c=3XZ$, we get $c=3Z-a-b$. Plug in the values we have obtained for $a$ and $b$. We get $c=3Z-3XZ-YZ\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: 3Z in the last, not 3XZ.